# Writing math formula

Tags: amsmath

Currently I'm having to write something like:

[image]

I'm writing "q" in the denominator as `|\vec{q}|` using the "pipe"; is it the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One way to do it is the following.

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}

\begin{document}
\[
\frac{\vec{q} \cdot \vec{r}_j}{\abs{\vec{q}\,} \times \abs{\vec{r}_j}}
\]
\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: A `\vec` without subscripts immediately followed by a bar clashes with it, so probably `\abs{\vec{q}\,}` is better.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm into LaTeX this is correct. I would put your formular as

```
$=\frac{\vec{q}\cdot\vec{r}_j}{|\vec{q}|\times|\vec{r}_j|}$
```

So for getting the absolute value typing the pipe `|` is fine. But do not use the pipe for some expression like

```
{a \in A | a \notin B}
```

instead use `\mid` there.

Comment: You'll get wrong spacing by using `|`s instead of `\lvert` and `\rvert`.